# Number of processes and threads in python vs what is shown in top

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I have following code (apology if the code is not logical - it is just for demo purposses):

```
import concurrent.futures
import math
import time

PRIMES_CHUNKG_A = [
    112272535095293,
    112582705942171,
    112272535095293
]

PRIMES_CHUNKG_B = [
    115280095190773,
    115797848077099,
    1099726899285419
]

PRIME_CHUMKS = [PRIMES_CHUNKG_A, PRIMES_CHUNKG_B]

def is_prime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False

    time.sleep(60)  # this is only for test purposses

    sqrt_n = int(math.floor(math.sqrt(n)))
    for i in range(3, sqrt_n + 1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def main_tp_chumks(prime_chumk):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        for number, prime in zip(prime_chumk, executor.map(is_prime, prime_chumk)):
            print('%d is prime: %s' % (number, prime))

def cmbine_pp_tp():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor_pp:
        executor_pp.map(main_tp_chumks, PRIME_CHUMKS)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time. time()
    cmbine_pp_tp()
    stop_time = time. time()
    print(f"Elapsed time - combined process/thread pool: {stop_time-start_time}")
```

[output from top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4biG6.png)

Both executors (processpool as well as threadpool) has set max_workers. The issue is that processpoolexecutor is set to 3 (max) yet top is showing 4 instances (see screenshot). As for threads there are also some disrepancies but they are not the main concern here. Due to fact that on my main code (not the demo one) it behaves exactly the same so I am suspecting that one of the process is acting like a "parent" but I cannot find anything about it. I tried to ask ChatGPT but I was told that there a lot of factors why this can happen. So I am not entirely sure. Can you help me to explain it why this i shappening?

I have checked official documentation as well as asked the AO, I have tested different settings for max_workers to sse how the numbers will differ. I always get for processpoolexecutor instances equeal to max_workers+1, as for threads they are (in demo) lower (but as mentioned) it is not reall "problem" here.

As for expectation - I would like to know why there are more processes than set by max_workers.

Comment: One initially started main process plus three workers is four.

Comment: From htop I saw that behaviour - but I would like to clarify that because my colleague is not beleiving me and even if showed him this simple code where there is nothing hidden he still thinks that I am creating the extra process by myself somewhere else. Is there any general documentation on this or something that could help to understand it and/or explain it to my colleague?

Comment: If your colleague truly believes that Processes can be magically created "somewhere else", without any actual code to do so, there is no logical argument or documentation that will convince him otherwise.

Comment: Thanks anyway. For the time being I will stick with the fact that one of the processes is the main one aka parent - at least it is shown in htop so I think that it should be sufficient.